# Next.js GetStaticProps Build For Multiple Environments Using Docker Image

Tags: docker, next.js, headless-cms

I have an application that is built & containerised using Docker.  The application uses Next.js, it communicates to a headless CMS and is pushed from environments dev, test, prod.  One image is built and the same image pushed to each environment to promote best practices.

My question is, with `getStaticProps` & `getStaticPaths` running at build time.  It requires the keys for the dev instance to contact the headless CMS in `getStaticPaths` so a list of valid pages can be statically generated. This will change per environment.  Doing this at build time seems impossible because it ties the environment to the statically generated pages at build time.

is there a recommended way of approaching this, without re-creating the image for each environment?

Comment: @SeanW with a single dockerfile and a single docker build, how can this be achieved using different . env files

Comment: It's not as easy as creating the files and putting them at the root, but there are a few ways - [this seems to be one of the simplest](https://raphaelpralat.medium.com/system-environment-variables-in-next-js-with-docker-1f0754e04cde)

Comment: How does this factor in for a single containerized image that needs to statically generate pages at build time not runtime?

Comment: I use a single docker image with multiple .env, and it builds my static sites with the correct variables.

Comment: Do you use getStaticPaths/Props though, for statically generated content? If so can you share your code please :)

Comment: I pursued this question on the nextjs github discussion. Linking here for reference.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16995